# PyInstaller is creating two unneeded folder 'Include' and 'PyInstaller'

Tags: python, include, exe, pyinstaller

I have a working Python 2.7 + Pyinstaller environment. But, the result of running the PyInstaller generates in the 'dist' folder an structure with two unneeded folder for my project. 
I don't know why they get into it, but the question is, how can I avoid them?
By 'unneeded' I mean that I can safely delete them from my folder's application.
Thanks in advance !!

```
dist
--> main
----> Include (unneeded)
------> pyconfig.h
----> PyInstaller (unneeded)
------> bootloader
------> lib
------> loader
------> utils
----> resources (my project's resource folder)
----> <more files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are needed when running the app on a computer without the correct version, or no version, of Python installed.

to have PyInstaller consolidate all of the resources into one executable, add the `--onefile` (or `-F` when shortened) option when using PyInstaller. The resulting single executable will auto-extract into a temp folder at runtime.